# How to get current logged in user id and match against a field?

Tags: process-builder

I am creating a process using process builder. I would like my action to be triggered when a certain condition is met on a custom object I have. The condition is that:

If the current user logged in ID matches the 'Owner' field on the custom object AND a field called 'brought' is not null in the custom object, then trigger the action.

I know how to check if a certain field is not null but I'm not sure how to get the user ID of the current logged in user and assert it against the Owner field in in my custom object. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The correct condition would be written as follows:

```
Field: [ObjectName].OwnerId
Operator: Equals
Type: Formula
Value: $User.Id
```

This condition will match the current user is owner criteria, then you just need to add your other criteria.